# how to know weather checkbox checked or not with javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function checkAll(custId){
        var id;
        if(document.getElementById(custId).checked == true){
        <%for (CustomerGroup custGroup : customerGroupList) {%>

            if(custId==<%=custGroup.getCustomerGroupId()%>){
                <%List<Account> list = accountDelegate
                    .findAccountEntityByGroupId(custGroup
                            .getCustomerGroupId());
            for (Account account : list) {%>
                        id=<%=account.getAccountId()%>
                        document.getElementById(id).checked=true;
                <%}%>
            }
    <%}%>
    }else {
        <%for (CustomerGroup custGroup : customerGroupList) {%>

            if(custId==<%=custGroup.getCustomerGroupId()%>){
            <%List<Account> list2 = accountDelegate
                    .findAccountEntityByGroupId(custGroup
                            .getCustomerGroupId());
            for (Account account : list2) {%>
                        id=<%=account.getAccountId()%>
                        document.getElementById(id).checked=false;
            <%}%>
    }
    <%}%>
}
}
```

Here I have passed custId as a id of checkbox.Problem here is if(document.getElementById(custId).checked == true

each time this condition will evaluate to false and thus control goes on else part.
so how can i know wether checkbox is cheched or not ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `checked` property is what you need to use to verify if a checkbox is checked:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        if (document.getElementById('test').checked) {
            alert('the checkbox is checked');
        }
    };  
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="test" name="test" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script language="javascript"><br>
 var test=document.getElementById('test');<br>

 if (test.checked == 1){<br>
          alert("yes,Checked") ;<br>
 }<br>
else<br>
{
<br>
 alert("No,Please Check.")<br>
 }<br>
 </script>
```

[code by www.neonbrains.com](http://www.neonbrains.com)

Comment: What additional information does this answer provide that was not already given in the other answer? Also, doing implicit type conversion (`test.checked == 1`) is really confusing in this case.